# How do we fit a pedestal sink top onto a vanity base?

Tags: bathroom, installation, sink, vanity

We want to put a rectangular pedestal sink top onto a wooden vanity (yet to be built). We won't be using a solid surface or laminate product on top, but instead want the sink to slightly overhang the cabinet on sides and front, creating an 'apron' look - the end result being that the cabinet itself will be slightly narrower and less deep then the sink top. (I want to clarify that I am not describing the look of a 'floating' sink on top of a countertop).

What is the best way to do this project correctly, and what are the considerations for making the sink-to-vanity attachment have a finished look?

Comment: So basically, you want to use a cabinet as the pedestal?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I am extremely curious why you want to do this. Does it have anything to do with the fact that it would be so unconventional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a trivial project, as apron front sinks have straight edges on the front sides and bottom.

2 cleats should span under the sink to support the weight.  They should be sturdy enough to make the cradle, perhaps 1x3 or 1x4, oriented like joists.  You could reinforce the cabinet sides with the same size boards laid flat and extending to the cabinet bottom (like posts).  Using two pocket screws on each end of the joist would give you a bit of adjustability. Just don't drive them home until you're happy with the positioning.

The side cuts and top cuts should be back cut to make final shaping easier.  Making a foam template will be helpful and easier than sanding the top.  Blue or pink EPS foam at 1 inch should fit your needs.  A jig saw, belt sander, and perhaps a rotary tool ( like Dremel) will be most useful.

Final affixing of bowl to top can be done by setting in a bead of sealant-caulk along top and front and perhaps a dot on each joist.

Comment: We are using a pedestal sink top (not officially an apron sink).  The cabinet will be built to fit the sink, replacing the porcelain pedestal. The sink will rest directly on top of the cabinet side-walls, with the sink slightly overhanging the cabinet walls, giving it the apron look on front and sides.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something like this (only hopefully fancier).

[image: Pedestal sink on cabinet]

You could simply build the cabinet in such a way, that there is a brace where the pedestal part *should* connect.

[image: Bracket to support sink]

Just make sure the brace is strong enough to support the sink, and has a way to connect the sink to it while also allowing the plumbing to pass through.

[image: pedestal brace]

***NOTE:*** These diagrams are only to illustrate a concept, and are not actual building plans. You'll want to insure all parts are designed to support whatever forces they may encounter.

Comment: This is exactly the concept we are looking for - and you're right that it will be fancier.  Thank You.